# How to calculate the date 30 days from today

Tags: javascript, date

i need to calculate the date from thirty days using `Date` in `javascript`

```
var now = new Date();
```

Example:

if today is the 13 February 2013, 30 days later is the 15 March 2013. so something that is different from `30DaysLaterMonth = ActualMonth+1.`

I hope my question is clear.. :)
thanks everybody!

Comment: Please note that there is no `Date()` in jQuery. What you are talking about is Javascript.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var now = new Date(); 
now.setDate(now.getDate() + 30);
```

Answer (score 10):

I think its better for you to use [**Datejs**](http://www.datejs.com/)

> Datejs is an open-source JavaScript Date Library.

or you can do it own:

```
var cur = new Date(),
    after30days = cur.setDate(cur.getDate() + 30);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var now = new Date();
var 30DaysLaterMonth = now.getDate() + 30;
```

Answer (score 0):

In native javascript, use `Date.UTC(year, month, day)`to get the number of milliseconds from 1971-01-01. Than add days * (86400000) and create date from this value:

```
var date_one_ms = Date.UTC(2012, 05, 25);
var ms_in_day = 24*3600*1000; // 86400000;
var date_30_days_later = new Date(date_one_ms + 30 * ms_in_day);
```

Comment: i think this is the more complex solution.. see the accepted answer to see what library opensource can do :)

Comment: I agree, the solution is more complex that te accepted one. Anyway, it reveals the inner working of a Date object and is usefull if you want to do date calculation based on other time slices like weeks or hours.

Comment: BTW You don't need Datejs for the accepted solution to work. It works in plain javascript.

Comment: i know.. but i prefer jquery :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date();
   d.setDate(d.getDate() + 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Get last 30 days form today**

```js
let now = new Date()
console.log(now)
let last30days = new Date(now.setDate(now.getDate() - 30))
console.log(last30days)
```

**Get next 30 days from today**

```js
let now = new Date()
console.log(now)
let next30days = new Date(now.setDate(now.getDate() + 30))
console.log(next30days)
```